# Setup Gunicorn with let's encrypt cert

Tags: ssl, gunicorn, lets-encrypt

To secure my website, I've used Let's encyprt `certbot` for generating `privkey.pem, cert.pem, chain.pem, and fullchain.pem`

When I connect my website from desktop chrome or firefox, it seems to be ok. but when I connect mobile browser such as chrome-android, It blocks connection and shows `untrusted certificate authority`.

I'm using Django==1.9.7 and gunicorn==19.6.0. and Here is my gunicorn configuration file:

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:443'
workers = 4
worker_class = 'gevent'
worker_connections = 1000
keepalive = 5

keyfile = 'privkey.pem'
certfile = 'cert.pem'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 19):

I've resolved this issue myself. The problem was caused by missing key chain file in the gunicorn configuration.

So, currently my configuration file is:

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:443'
workers = 4
worker_class = 'gevent'
worker_connections = 1000
keepalive = 5

keyfile = 'privkey.pem'
certfile = 'cert.pem'
ca_certs = 'chain.pem'
```

Comment: could you share the command, which you used to run gunicorn., I would like to run gunicorn alone without a reverse proxy like apache or nginx